# allow contributor users to add web parts to a page without granting them “Add and Customize Pages” permission

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, permissions, design

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection, and when contributor users try to add web parts they will get the following error:-

> A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or
>   imported. You don't have Add and Customize Pages permissions required
>   to perform this action.

So I granted the Contribute Permission level an extra permission which is “Add and Customize Pages”. Now contributors will be able to add/edit/delete web parts. But they will have extra permissions that I do not want them to have , such as changing the design and customize some page layouts, also they can access the site settings and create site columns !!.

So my question is basically if there is another way to allow users with contribute permission to be able to add web parts without granting any extra permission. In other words to treat adding web parts as normal content such as image, Text ,tables ?

Thanks